# Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 Application Development

Tags: windows-8

Do I have to get the developer license for develop a basic sample application on windows 8? I tired open a windows store project with visual studio 2012 and it says get a developer licence. I can not see the design mode. I can not see anything how my application looks like? I can not run it. How can I run with debug on visual studio without a developer licence? I just want to develop a basic application and run it on my windows 8 system? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a developer license you only need a live ID, so it's basically a 30 seconds act to gain one. After that you freely build&run projects on your computer.

Comment: To submit your apps to store you should pay, however you can develop apps for free.The first time you create a Win8 app in Visual Studio it offer you to get a developer license but it's just formality not a "you can submit app to store" type licence. If your VS doesn't work right, than it's a problem with your computer.

Comment: I tired login with my outlook.com account now it is ok. It is really formality :)

Comment: The process is described in more detail here: Submitting your App to the Windows Store and Avoiding Common Submission Errors http://bit.ly/VPHCr5